# Algorithm to get approximate equation of a graph based on a set of points

Tags: php, algorithm, linear-algebra

I have a MySQL database with a variety of constantly updating data sets that are generally matchable to a linear or quadratic-type pattern. Are there any existing libraries, preferentially with PHP, that I can use to estimate an equation from a set of data points for predicting future data points?

Answer (score 2):

Can't answer about the libraries, but the basic process in "[Linear Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)". The process isn't that difficult, so you can probably write your own fairly quickly. As an aside, Postgres can has statistic functions built in that do that, MySQL might has something like that. At least now you know what to look for.